# Menu not open when clicking open button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have one problem with my menu.

This is the problem **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/mJOBqQ)** from codepen.io

In this demo you can see there is a left sidebar menu area. When you change the browser size `width < 1050px` then the menu `opacity:0;` and the button will showing on top left side (blue button).

The problem is left sidebar not opening when i click the button. The working example is here **without** *css media screen*.

Working **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/BNQwYg)** *without css media screen*

Here is a code:

HTML

```
<div class="header-left">
  Change browser size width < 1050px
  <div class="menu-area">
    <div class="icon-header-home-menu menu-show-hide">Click to Show Button now</div>
    <div class="menu-area-wrap ">
      <div class="menu-item-info">MENU AREA</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.header-left{
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background-color:black;
  color:#ffffff;
  padding:10px;
}
.menu-area {
  float: left;
}
.icon-header-home-menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color:blue;
}
.menu-area-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  width: 230px;
  height: 800px;
  top: 42px;
  left: 52px;
  background-color:red;
}
.menu-item-info {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background-color:green;
}
.menu-area-wrap.active {
  opacity:1;
  -webkit-transform-origin: right top 0px; 
  -webkit-transform: scale(1); 
}
.menu-show-hide{
  display:none;
}
@media all and (max-width: 1050px) {
    .menu-show-hide {
       display:block;   
        }

    .menu-area-wrap{
  position: absolute;
  top: 42px;
  left:0;    /*changed here*/
  width:100%;  /*changed here*/
  z-index: 1000;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  background: #009688;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  display:none;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left top 0px; 
  -webkit-transform: scale(0); 
    opacity:0;
}

    }
```

JS

```
$('html').click(function() {
  $('.menu-area-wrap').removeClass("active");
});


$(".icon-header-home-menu").click (function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('.menu-area-wrap').toggleClass("active");
});

 $('.menu-area-wrap').click (function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Be sure that your javascript (jQuery) selectors are running after your html loads.

Comment: @KJPrice I wanted to help because I can not do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this **inside** your media screen:

```
.menu-area-wrap.active {
    display: block;
}
```

Your media screen has `display: none` while your active class doesn't have `display:block`.

So, in desktop you were changing opacity but in mobile you are changing displays, therefore, your active class won't do anything because it still has `display:none` overwriting your `opacity: 0`.

```js
$('html').click(function() {
  $('.menu-area-wrap').removeClass("active");
});


$(".tt").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('.menu-area-wrap').toggleClass("active");
});

$('.menu-area-wrap').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.header-left {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px;
}
.menu-area {
  float: left;
}
.icon-header-home-menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.menu-area-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  width: 230px;
  height: 800px;
  top: 42px;
  left: 52px;
  background-color: red;
}
.menu-item-info {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background-color: green;
}
.menu-area-wrap.active {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform-origin: right top 0px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
}
.menu-show-hide {
  display: none;
}
@media all and (max-width: 1050px) {
  .menu-show-hide {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu-area-wrap.active {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu-area-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 42px;
    left: 0;
    /*changed here*/
    width: 100%;
    /*changed here*/
    z-index: 1000;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
    background: #009688;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    display: none;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left top 0px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header-left">
  Change browser size width
  < 1050px <div class="menu-area">
    <div class="icon-header-home-menu tt menu-show-hide">Click to Show Button now</div>
    <div class="menu-area-wrap ">
      <div class="menu-item-info">MENU AREA</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

### With animation:

Removed the `display: none` in mobile.

```js
$('html').click(function() {
  $('.menu-area-wrap').removeClass("active");
});


$(".tt").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('.menu-area-wrap').toggleClass("active");
});

$('.menu-area-wrap').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.header-left {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px;
}
.menu-area {
  float: left;
}
.icon-header-home-menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.menu-area-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  width: 230px;
  height: 800px;
  top: 42px;
  left: 52px;
  background-color: red;
}
.menu-item-info {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background-color: green;
}
.menu-area-wrap.active {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform-origin: right top 0px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
}
.menu-show-hide {
  display: none;
}
@media all and (max-width: 1050px) {
  .menu-show-hide {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu-area-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 42px;
    left: 0;
    /*changed here*/
    width: 100%;
    /*changed here*/
    z-index: 1000;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
    background: #009688;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left top 0px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .menu-area-wrap.active {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform-origin: right top 0px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header-left">
  Change browser size width
  < 1050px <div class="menu-area">
    <div class="icon-header-home-menu tt menu-show-hide">Click to Show Button now</div>
    <div class="menu-area-wrap ">
      <div class="menu-item-info">MENU AREA</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `display:none;` and `display:block;` working on there. But if i use `display:block;` and `display:none;` the opening animation not working on that time.

Comment: @innovation check snippet I've added. secondly, you can't animate `display:none` and `display:block` changes. so, I recommend you animate the height instead. set it to 0 when closed and the size you want when opened. instead of display.

Comment: @innovation added snippet with animation. check it.